# Saving data on my mysql server on my wordpress website

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to create baseball database on mysql server for my Wordpress website. (I think my website comes with 3GB mysql server) I am creating r shiny app for baseball data analysis. I initially included 1GB of csv with my rshiny app, which really slowed down the analysis. Now I want to connect my rshiny app with mysql database I want to host online. I thought of uploading the data to my mysql server on my wordpress. Will that work? Does mysql server that came with my Wordpress serve that purpose?